# io-ts how to use a custom union as type to be checked at run time

Tags: typescript, fp-ts, io-ts-library

I would like to use a custom union, or generally a custom type in io-ts.

I receive an error in this like

`T.array(T.type(MyUnion))`

Could you please tell me what is the right way to achieve this?

```
import * as T from 'io-ts';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

console.clear();

type MyUnion = 'item-a' | 'item-b' | 'item-c';

const test1 = T.type({
  data: T.array(T.string),
});


pipe(test1.decode({ data: ['hello'] }), E.fold(console.error, console.log)); // OK

const test2 = T.type({
  data: T.array(T.type(MyUnion)), // ERROR
});

pipe(test2.decode({ data: ['hello'] }), E.fold(console.error, console.log));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a variable named `MyUnion` so you can use at runtime first:

```
const MyUnion = T.union([T.literal("item-a"), T.literal("item-b"), T.literal("item-c")]);
```

but it's quite redundant to use this again:

```
type MyUnion = 'item-a' | 'item-b' | 'item-c';
```

Fortunately, io-ts has a built-in type `TypeOf` that gets the type of an io-ts type as a TS type, which removes the redundancy:

```
type MyUnion = T.TypeOf<typeof MyUnion>;
//   ^? 'item-a' | 'item-b' | 'item-c'
```

Then you'll be able to use `MyUnion` as both an io-ts type (at runtime), and a TS type (at compile-time):

```
const test2 = T.type({
  data: T.array(MyUnion), // ok
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlLqQN)